# Почему функция возвращает None, если значения return заданы?

Tags: python

Пишу алгоритм на графе - поиск в глубину. Суть определить является ли один класс предком другого класса.
Класс A является предком класса B, если
A = B;
A - прямой предок B
существует такой класс C, что C - прямой предок B и A - предок C

Почему функция возвращает None, если значения return заданы?

```
def find_predky(self,predok,potomok):
    
    if potomok not in self.dict_class:
        return "No"
    
    if predok in self.dict_class[potomok]:
        return "Yes"
    
    if predok==potomok:
        return "Yes"
            
    for mas_prdk in self.dict_class[potomok]:
        for prdk in mas_prdk:
            return self.find_predky(predok, prdk)
```

Это полный код:

```
input = open("input2.txt", "r").readline

strInput=''

class request:
     
    def __init__(self):
        self.mas_request=[]
        
    def add_reqwest(self, str_input):
        self.mas_request.append(str_input.split())
        return True
        

class inheritance:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict_class=dict()
        self.visited=set()
        
        
    def add_class(self,str_input):
            
         potomoc_predoc=str_input.split(':')
         potomoc=potomoc_predoc[0].replace(' ', '').replace('\n','')
         if len(potomoc_predoc)>1:
             predky=[predok.replace(' ', '') for predok in potomoc_predoc[1].split()]
         else:
            predky=[]
         
         if potomoc not in self.dict_class:
             self.dict_class[potomoc]=predky
         else:
             for x in predky:
                 self.dict_class[potomoc].append(x)
                 
            
    def find_predky(self,predok,potomok):
        
        if potomok not in self.dict_class:
            return "No"
        
        if predok in self.dict_class[potomok]:
            return "Yes"
        
        if predok==potomok:
            return "Yes"
                
        for mas_prdk in self.dict_class[potomok]:
            for prdk in mas_prdk:
                return self.find_predky(predok, prdk)
            
        

count_class=int(input())

inher=inheritance()

for i in range(count_class):
    inher.add_class(input())
 
count_request=int(input())

rqwst=request()

for i in range(count_request):
    rqwst.add_reqwest(input())
        
for rq in rqwst.mas_request:
    print(inher.find_predky(rq[0],rq[1]))
```

На вход в строке:

```
input = open("input2.txt", "r").readline
```

Подаю файл со следующим содержимым (переносы строк здесь не учитываются):

> Классы потомки и предки

- 12
- G : F
- A
- B : A
- C : A
- D : B C
- E : D
- F : D
- X
- Y : X A
- Z : X
- V : Z Y
- W : V
- 

> Запросы

- 8
- A G
- A Z
- A W
- X W
- X QWE
- A X
- X X
- 1 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятнее всего у вас в `self.dict_class[potomok]` лежит пустой массив и поэтому цикл `for` не выполняется

Вот пример, хоть `return` присутствует выводить `None`

```
def f(list_):
    for el in list_:
        return el

print(f([]))
```

Comment: Добавил проверку: ''' for mas_prdk in self.dict_class[potomok]:
          if len(mas_prdk)==0:
                return "No"
            for prdk in mas_prdk:
                return self.find_predky(predok, prdk) ''' но результат тоже

Comment: Так может `self.dict_class[potomok]` пуст? => в цикл не заходим => условие не проверяется

Comment: Там в любом случае должен быть пустой массив, поэтому первый for должен вернуть пусть пустой массив, но массив, а вот уже 2-ой for, если массив пустой может ничего и не вернуть `if len(potomoc_predoc)>1:
             predky=[predok.replace(' ', '') for predok in potomoc_predoc[1].split()]
         else:
            predky=[]
         
         if potomoc not in self.dict_class:
             self.dict_class[potomoc]=predky`

Comment: Он разве пустой массив не должен передать во 2-ой for?

Comment: Всё-таки получается, что он пустой массив во внутренний `for` не передает, хотя это странно как-то, потому что там же не `None`,а пустой массив. Но судя потому что когда поставил проверку перед внешним `for` ошибка ушла это так `if len(self.dict_class[potomok])==0:
            return "No"
                
        for mas_prdk in self.dict_class[potomok]:
            for prdk in range(len(mas_prdk)):
                if self.find_predky(predok, mas_prdk[prdk])=='Yes':
                    return 'Yes'
                return self.find_predky(predok, mas_prdk[prdk])
            return 'No'`